# global string array in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global

As you can see, I have defined a global variable called filas, which in the function get_filas (full_text), I assign it the value full_text.split (": & ^").Then I must use that assigned value in the following function () but I get the following console output: Unncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

How then is it possible to define the rows variable and assign it a data to then use them in another function?

var filas;

```
var cantidad_de_eventos_vistos;

window.onload = function(){
  get_data();

  var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
  ul.onclick = function(event) {
      var target = getEventTarget(event);
      alert(target.innerHTML);
  };

cantidad_de_eventos_vistos=2;

}

function get_data(){
  console.log("algo");
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://192.168.0.248:10000'
  request.open("POST", url, true);
  var header="@:::|$&!";
  var mensaje = "get_data"
  request.send(header+mensaje);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(request.responseText);
    get_filas(request.responseText);
  }
}
}

function get_filas(texto_completo){
  filas=texto_completo.split(":&^");
  if (2 < filas.length){
    for (var i = 1; i < 2+1; i++) {
      var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute('id',filas[i].split(";¬")[0]);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filas[i].split(";¬")[0]));
      ul.appendChild(li);
      cantidad_de_eventos_vistos=cantidad_de_eventos_vistos+2;
      }
      btn_siguiente.style.visibility="visible"
  }
  else{
    for (var i = 1; i < filas.length; i++) {
      var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
      var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute('id',filas[i].split(";¬")[0]);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filas[i].split(";¬")[0]));
      ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

}

function siguiente(){
  var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
  ul.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
  for (var i = 1+cantidad_de_eventos_vistos; i < cantidad_de_eventos_vistos+2+1; i++) {
    var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id',filas[i].split(";¬")[0]);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filas[i].split(";¬")[0]));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if(cantidad_de_eventos_vistos!=filas.length){
      cantidad_de_eventos_vistos=cantidad_de_eventos_vistos+2;
      btn_siguiente.style.visibility="hide";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing the function `get_filas` an undefined value or a value that is not a string.

Comment: It is at siguiente() function where there is the problem. I am using filas which is a global variable

Comment: Yes but `get_filas` sets a value for the `filas` variable and the variable `cantidad_de_eventos_vistos` which is used in the `siguiente` function the so how you call `get_filas` is relevant. Most likely what is happening is the at some iteration in your loop in the `siguiente` function `filas[i]` does not exist and a `split` is performed on a value of `undefined`. This situation is exactly what you should avoid setting global variables from two different functions. You need to debug this issue yourself by using breakpoints or `console.log`

Comment: thanks but what I want is to have the files variable as a global variable, which I can set a value and use it or read it in every function